# Android devices shows up in wrong account on Google Dashboard

Tags: google-account, accounts, google-apps

I noticed today that my Android device shows up in the Google Dashboard for my work (Google Apps) address, as opposed to the Google Dashboard for my personal address.

I am wondering if this is even an issue? Of course I would prefer to have it associated with my personal account dashboard.

I have not tried to remedy the issue yet. Maybe my first step would be to delete the work account on my Android and see if it would default to a different account. As far as I can tell there is no option for changing a "default account" with which your Android associates.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The default account is the one that you logged in with first. If this was your Apps account and the "Remove account" option doesn't work than on a non-rooted device the only way to remedy this I to perform a Factory reset. However the device will still show up on your dashboard, I have devices I stopped using two years ago still there.

One other thing to note is that your phone should show up on **all** accounts that you're logged in with. If it doesn't, try downloading a free app with that account.